Variational problem with inequality constraint
I am trying to minimize the following functional:
$$
\int_0^1 ( f'(t)^2 + g'(t)^2 - 2 \, r f'(t) g'(t) ) \, dt 
$$
over all pairs $(f, g)$ such that $f(t) \geq f_0(t)$ and $g (t) \geq g_0(t)$ for all $t$. Here $g_0(t)$ and $f_0(t)$ are some fixed functions and $r \in (0, 1)$.
If $r < 0$, the $f$ and $g$ are the smallest non-decreasing concave majorants of $f_0$ and $g_0$. If $r > 0$, however, I do not know how to approach the problem, but I expect something similar.
I've tried taking the following Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal{L} = f'^2 + g'^2 - 2 r f' g' + \lambda ( f - f_0 ) + \mu (g - g_0).
$$
Then the Euler-Lagrange equations are
$$
2f''(t) - 2rg''(t) = \lambda(t) \quad \text{and} \quad
2g''(t) - 2 r f''(t) = \mu (t),
$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Wouldn't there be a couple more equations related to $\lambda$ and $\mu?$ I mean, right now you can easily solve for $f''$ and $g'',$ but without the additional information from two more equations, you wouldn't be able to finish.
